# react-native limit List items

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, listview, react-native

i am using [Flatlist](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html) from react-native and [ListItem](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/API/lists/) from react-native-elements,

i want to initially limit the number of list-items that are loaded on the screen.Otherwise it loads all the items that i have initially .

Suppose i have 300 list items but initially i only want to load 10 items ,instead of 300.

MY CODE:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {
   FlatList
} from 'react-native'

import {Avatar,Tile,ListItem} from 'react-native-elements'

export default class Login extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props);


this.state = {
  data:[],
   dataSource: []

    };
  }


renderList(item,i){


  return(

<View>
<ListItem

subtitle={
<Avatar
  small
  rounded
  source={{uri: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/ladylexy/128.jpg"}}

/>
{<Text>{item.body}</Text>}
}

/>
<View>
    )
}

render(){  
    return( 
        <View>
<List>
<FlatList
        data={this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        renderItem ={({item,index}) => this.renderList(item,index)}
      />
</List>  
</View>
      )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically, what you need is to implement sort of pagination. You can do it by using `onEndReached` and `onEndReachedThreshold`(for more details look [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html#onendreachedthreshold)) of `FlatList` to load more data when user reaches the end of list.

You can change your code like so:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList } from 'react-native';

import { Avatar, Tile, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';

const initialData = [0,...,299]; //all 300. Usually you receive this from server or is stored as one batch somewhere
const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 10; // what is the batch size you want to load.
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [0,..., 9], // you can do something like initialData.slice(0, 10) to populate from initialData.
      dataSource: [],
      page: 1,
    };
  }

  renderList(item, i) {
    return (
      <View>
        <ListItem />
      </View>
    );
  }

  loadMore() {
    const { page, data } = this.state;
    const start = page*ITEMS_PER_PAGE;
    const end = (page+1)*ITEMS_PER_PAGE-1;

    const newData = initialData.slice(start, end); // here, we will receive next batch of the items
    this.setState({data: [...data, ...newData]}); // here we are appending new batch to existing batch
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => this.renderList(item, index)}
          onEndReached={this.loadMore}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: isn't this missing a `this.setState({page: page + 1})` ?