# How to Render only few elements in FlatList

Tags: react-native

I am having say about 100 elements in my array/object

I am using **FlatList** to display it

```
   <FlatList
    data={this.props.redditCryptoNews}
     maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
    renderItem={({index, item}) => {
     return (
        <Text style={RedditList}>{item["data"]["title"]}</Text>)}} />
```

Now, I just want to display just **10 element**s in my flatlist instead of displaying all **100 elements**

For some reason, I think Facebook haven't done good job with its react-native documentation which makes it sort of hard for me to comprehend

**[Question:]** How Can I achieve it?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45323007/react-native-limit-list-items

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay, It was stupid of me.

We can simply slice the data we are passing.

```
 <FlatList
    data={this.props.redditCryptoNews.slice(0,5)}
     maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
    renderItem={({index, item}) => {
     return (
        <Text style={RedditList}>{item["data"]["title"]}</Text>)}} />
```

Notice `.slice(0,5)` here

```
  data={this.props.redditCryptoNews.slice(0,5)}
```